# How to know the console port number of Android Emulator to which it is bound?

Tags: android, emulation, adb

I need to know, how I get console port to which android emulator is connected programmatically. I am using library com.android.ddmlib.

To be more specific: Let's say that I have already started some emulator and when I execute some program, it checks if there is some emulator on some port (e.g. 5554). If it is, the output is true, otherwise false.

I can access all devices (IDevice) from android debug bridge, but I am not able to realize, if that particular device is bound to some specific port.

All I see is the output from adb devices -l, but it writes only "emulator-5554". Is it the only way how to realize the port?

Answer (score 1):

The command `adb start-server` shows the message,

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port xxxx *
```

"xxxx" is the port number which is being used by `adb`.

Comment: I thought every started emulator has own adb port by which it speaks to the adb server. E.g when I start an emulator, there is option "--ports <consoleport>,<adbport>" so I can have teoretically several different adb servers which are listening at some dedicated ports to which all emulators are bound? It is said there are two ports every emulator is bound to, console port and adb port, even and odd number, by default consecutive ones and I guess two emulators are not able to use the same adb port (by default adb=console+1). I am asking, how do I realize to which adb port is an emulator bound.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
adb devices
```

And console gives you something like this

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```